# Confirmación de salida de un fragmentdas

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, alertdialog, fragment, ciclo-de-vida

Me encuentro realizando una app, la cual utiliza **BottonNavigationView**. Estoy cambiando de fragments y la aplicación funciona correctamente. Pero necesito que en algunos fragments antes de salir de ellos (sea porque presionó atras o selecciono una opción en la barra de navegación) aparezca un Dialog que pregunte si desea o no salir del fragment. He intentado lo siguiente:

1.He tratado de utilizar el metodo **onPause** pero cuando se muestra el Dialog ya el fragment se ha cerrado y no puedo hacer la gestion del cerrado del fragment.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    //Metodo que me gestiona la aparición del Dialog y funtion es la rutina que se ejecutará si se acepta salir del fragment.
    alertDialog(
        title = "Salida",
        message = "Esta seguro que desea salir?",
        funtion = {super.onPause()}
    )
}
```

2. He tratado de gestionar si se presiona el boton atras pero esto no cubriria si se sale del fragmente de otra forma.

Lo que tengo pensado si es posible, que una vez llegue al metodo **onPause** se pueda decidir si seguir el ciclo de vida del fragment (pasar al onStop y/o onDestroy) o quedarse en él.
Les agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Esta función deberías ponerla en el onDestroy y realizar la acción en el caso que sea afirmativa la respuesta por parte del usuario.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    alertDialog(
        title = "Salida",
        message = "Esta seguro que desea salir?",
        funtion = {super.onDestroy()}
    )
}
```